# #XPATH Remove nodesets that don't exist twice

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have a requirement where I need to filter out all nodesets that don't appear double in the input XML.

My source file consists of 2 messages combined in 1 XML. Both messages can have the same notesets, however, message 1 can have additional nodesets that need to be filtered out:

```
<messages>
<msg1>
    <element1>
        <a>dummy field</a>
        <b>22222</b>
        <c>33333</c>
    </element1>
    <element2>
    <d>4444444</d>
    </element2>
</msg1>
<msg2>
    <element1>
        <b>22222</b>
        <c>33333</c>
    </element1>
</msg2>
```

As you can see, both msg1 and msg2 have fields b and c. Field a in msg1 can be ignored, as this contains a dummy value. So that means element1 node with its child fields is the same in msg 1 and msg2. However, element2 doesn't exist in msg2 and therfore should be deleted from the output file. The output file I expect is:

```
<messages>
    <msg1>
        <element1>
            <a>dummy field</a>
            <b>22222</b>
            <c>33333</c>
        </element1>
    </msg1>
    <msg2>
        <element1>
            <b>22222</b>
            <c>33333</c>
        </element1>
    </msg2>
</messages>
```

Thanks a million times for who can help out!

Comment: Is the name of the element all that is relevant to check there is a duplicate? Or the value as well? Also any attributes?

Comment: Yes, the value as well.. So all child nodes including their values..

Comment: Would the `<d>4444444</d>` element, which is under `element2` be considered the same as as `<d>4444444</d>` that was under `element1` in msg2?

Comment: I think this needs a much more rigorous specification before you start coding.

Comment: @Tim; no. Because they have a different parent ('element1' vs 'element2')